# How to access custom fields in the category of a relationship field in expressionengine?

Tags: expressionengine

I have a custom field on my category group, called colour. I'm using a relationship field to pull the categories of the related entry into my page, but can't figure out how to get the 'colour' of the category of the related entry.

Getting the name of the category works fine by using

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="parent"}
    {related_entry}
        {related_entry:categories}
            {category_name}
        {/related-entry:categories}
    {/related_entry}
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

so I would've assumed that accessing the custom field would be possible in a similar way, such as

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="parent"}
    {related_entry}
        {related_entry:categories}
            {colour}
        {/related-entry:categories}
    {/related_entry}
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

but I'm having no luck. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it supposed to be like this? I think in your sample code, the category_name is parsed from the channel entries and not from the related_entry.

```
{related_entry:categories:category_name} and {related_entry:categories:colour}
```